# How to reply private message with facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I've managed to do a reading of the data on the facebook page private message me. Then I want to reply to the sender but failed.

My app permission : `manage_pages, read_page_mailboxes`

My code :

```
require '../src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '339554932xxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'zzz334534123xx',
));

$pages = $facebook->api('/me/accounts');

foreach ($pages['data'] as $page) {
        $page_access_token = $page['access_token'];
}

$MsgRep = "This is a reply message...";
$MID    = "m_mid.1393481292907:f67352f5dfd39b5e42";
$facebook->api('/'.$MID.'/messages', 'POST', array('message' =>$MsgRep, 'access_token' => $page_access_token));
echo "Message Sent";
```

The result: But I just get a blank screen. without `echo "Message Sent"`

Is there something wrong with my code?

Thanks

Comment: Probably, you are getting error. Have you checked php log file?

Comment: I cant find error_log @HüseyinBABAL

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: you have two problems, that for each isn't right and your not capturing the result of the api, `$message_response = $facebook->api('/'.$MID.'/messages', 'POST', array('message' =>$MsgRep, 'access_token' => $page_access_token));
var_dump($message_response);
echo "Message Sent";`